# tf.einsum matrix multiplication for different shape of tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors, `a.shape = (?, 8, 448, 448, 64)` representing (batch, head, height, weight, depth), `b.shape = (895, 64)`, I want to get a new tensor `c` whose shape is (?, 8, 448, 448, 895). I used below code but failed with error: `Subscripts have incorrect format`

```
c = tf.einsum('bhlwd,nd−>bhlwn', a, b)
```

how to do it? except for `tf.einsum`, any other way to do it?

Comment: You are using a [minus-sign](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2212) (\u2212) instead of a [hyphen](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002D) (\u002D). I guess this is a copy paste error.

Comment: yes, true, thank you @Lescurel